# Set dynamically VertScrollBar property of the form based on label height - c++ builder

Tags: c++, forms, scrollbar, c++builder, c++builder-6

I'm using C++Builder 6.

I have a Form contain a `TLabel`.

I would like that the Form will contain a scroll bar when needed since sometimes the label text is too large to display.

What happens now is that the Form height grows as the Label height grows.

I would like that the Form height will be always <= a variable that I define, and that the `VertScrollBar` will appear when the label height is > that limit.

How to set the `VertScrollBar` property of the Form to support this?

Mainly, how to set the position and the range?

Comment: I think you would be having more luck setting your own scroll bar not the `Form`'s.  You can easily set the Position,Min,Max property (in the right order so you do not make an exception) but the rendering of labels will not be synchronized. Instead of labels I would Render the texts on my own with OnPaint event with Form1->Canvas->TextOutA(x,y,"string"); you can use scrollbar position to cut the part of strings you need.... Mono-spaced fonts are a good start point for this (like `OEM_CHARSET, System, fpFixed`). Or you can have virtual screen (Bitmap) with full size and copy rectangle ...

Answer (score 0):

Set the Form's `Contraints.MaxHeight` property to the desired limit value, and set its `AutoScroll` property to true. Let the VCL manage the Form's scrollbars for you automatically when its content exceeds its width/height.

Alternatively, I would suggest getting rid of the `TLabel` and use a `TRichEdit`<sup>1</sup> instead.  Set its `WordWrap` to true, and its `ScrollBars` to `ssVertical`.  It will auto-hide the scrollbar when it is not needed.

<sup>1</sup>: `TMemo` has the same `ScrollBars` property, but it does not hide the scrollbar when it is not needed.